# Apache Flume Custom zip Deserializer to split Events

Tags: flume-ng

I am using Apache Flume 1.6.0.SNAPSHOT to read a zip file containing multiple XML files. I want to represent each XML as an event. I tried following the BlobDeserializer example but I am unable to split the events based on the number of XMLs. Can somebody please help me on this.
Thanks